# display webpage content using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am learning beautifulsoup for web scraping. My question is can I display the content similar with what we see from a normal webpage?

I tried this:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
url="www.mywebsite.com"
html=urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
body=soup.body.text
body=body.encode('ascii','ignore')
print body
```

However the output seems  messy ,too much stuff I don't want to display. Is there any better way?Thanks in advance.

update: I want to get the text displayed on the webpage. Since different webpage are formatted differently,I might not know which tag(span,li,...) I need to extract. My target is to extract as much information as possible.

Comment: do you mean, stripping the html tags?

Comment: if so, there is a recipe for that here: https://gist.github.com/braveulysses/120191

Comment: `body=soup.body.text` this will extract as much information as possible.  If that is too much information and you don't know the tags it will be in I don't see what you can do.  If you want to filter stuff out you need to tell bs4 something to filter on.